# Rails autoloader not loading module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have the following structure in my /lib folder

```
/lib
   /example
      /foo
         bar.rb
      foo.rb
```

**foo.rb**

```
module Example
   module Foo
      def self.some_methods
      end
   end
end
```

**bar.rb**

```
module Example
    module Foo
        class Bar
           ...
        end
    end
end
```

I then have in **application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

and in an initializer

```
...
Example::Foo.some_methods
...
```

I'm running into problems when trying to run my test suite in that it seems to be failing when setting up the Rails environment. It's complaining that `some_methods` does not exist on `Example::Foo`. I can boot a local development server up without any errors, however.

Digging into the problem using a breakpoint, the `Example::Foo` module is defined at the point of failure, but it's empty. I am assuming that the autoloader is loading `bar.rb` first (I can access that class in the initializer no problems)? It seems to be the case that Rails doesn't try to load `foo.rb` as `Example::Foo` has already been defined by `bar.rb`?

What's happening? If I require `foo.rb` in the initializer it works, but it feels like a bad solution. Also, any idea why this problem would only surface when running `rake spec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of the autoloader is that it loads **missing** constants by turning a module/class hierarchy into a path. As you've defined your constant in two files, it will never automatically load the second file.

You need to manually require your `foo.rb`.

Comment: Makes sense! Any thoughts on the best place to require the file?